# Is it possible to place ERB into a simple_form placeholder string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, simple-form

I have a form that has placeholder text.  I would like to be able to make part of it dynamic.  It seems so simple but I can't figure it out.  What am I missing?

Here's the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@reviewable, @review]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :review, :input_html => { :class => "span4", :rows => 10 },
                label: false,                                
                placeholder: 'Help others by sharing what you\'ve learned as a major.' %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn cancel-modal-review" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <%= f.submit 'Share My Review', :class => "submit-feedback" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want the placeholder text to read something along these lines:

```
placeholder: 'Help others by sharing what you\'ve learned as a <%= @major.name %> major.'
```

But when I do that it reads literal "Help others by sharing what you've learned as a <%= @major.name %> major."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you place your string within single quotes it will be shown literally. With double quotes your result inside #{} is parsed correctly.

Try this:

```
placeholder: "Help others by sharing what you\'ve learned as a #{@major.name} major."
```

Comment: Thank you!  I had tried #{@major.name} too but I overlooked the double quotes.  Thank you so much!